# AWS Custom Authorization lambda to approve Api Gateway service proxy action?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to create an Api Gateway route which is connected via service proxy to s3.

Only authenticated and authorized users (from Cognito Userpool) which have a specific permission (which is stored in a DynamoDb table) should be able to upload the file.

Since I'm not using S3 as the service proxy and not lambda, is it ok to put the code checking against the Dynamodb in the Custom Authorizer lambda? (After the token has been verified and before sending the success callback).

The query is simple, based on the Cognito user unique Id, I check in a table that user if user is authorized to upload.

I wouldn't want the upload to be done via a lambda function since some files are big.

Thanks

Comment: Yeah that is pretty simple, makes sense to me. Any other option wouldn't really allow you to control access directly via the Dynamo table.

Comment: Hello @Guy Wald,


did you actually go through with this solution? Could you please share your experience? 

It might help me out on a similar requirement i am working on rn.

Answer (score 2):

You can also consider

- Setup CloudFront infront of S3 bucket.
- Using IAM authorization at API Gateway.
- Write a Lambda endpoint which checks Cognito ID in request context against Dynamodb.
- Return [Signed URL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html) from Lambda for authorized users to directly upload files to S3 from browser client.